# Finding affine transformation that best fits two one arbitrary two-dimensional function to another arbitrary two-dimensional function?

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations

The general formulation of the problem I'm trying to solve, in the discrete two-dimensional case would be as follows:

We have functions $F_1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and similarly for $F_2$. For simplicity, let's assume they're nonzero only over a subset of the x-y plane; for simplicity, say the rectangle $-W < x < W$ and $-H < y < H$ for some $W > 0$, $H>0$.

Further, let's consider the discrete case, where we only have the values of the functions at points $\mathbf{X}_k = (x_k,y_k)^\mathrm{T}$. Let us also assume that these points form a square grid. (basically, the practical application I am describing is a photograph of something — matching one photograph to another when there is little, or hard to extract, information about the structure of the shapes/objects in the photographs)

The problem is: find the affine transformation ($2\times 2$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ rpresenting a linear transformation and two-dimensional column vector $\mathbf{b}$ representing the translation) such that the error function $e$ is minimized: $$e = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \big|F_1(\mathbf{A\cdot X}_k + \mathbf{b}) - F_2(\mathbf{X}_k) \big|^2$$

Roughly speaking, this is related to the problem of matching one shape to another, but a solution as described above is general enough that does not need to make assumptions on the structure of the images, or determine precise correspondence between points in the images.

Comment: Are you asking about how to minimize the expression?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes: minimize in the sense of: find $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ that produce the lowest value of $e$

Comment: I think that gradient descent or Lucas-Kanade is the way to go.

Comment: Hmmm, but the functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ are not in closed form, so I cannot analytically take their derivatives. Actually, since we are talking about the derivatives with respect to the elements of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, it looks like we wouldn't even be able to obtain numerical approximations of the derivatives (am I missing something?)

Comment: Numerical derivatives all the way, then, as in LK

Comment: I do not see how LK applies .... however, I can see how gradient descent applies, and it just hit me that computing the derivatives is completely a non-issue; I just have a composite function $F_1(a_{11}x + a_{12}y + b_1, \cdots)$, so $\partial F_1 / \partial a_{11}$ is simply the derivative of $F_1$ _with respect to the first coordinate of its argument_ (not to be confused with $x$, the $x$-coordinate in my image), times $x$ (the derivative of the inner function w.r.t. $a_{11}$). Then, the derivative of $F_1$ w.r.t. its first argument, that one I obtain numerically from the image. (right?)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by LK:  $I_{x,y}$ are estimated by numerical differentiation of the intensity.